# Jest Enzyme how to shallow test for existence of wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a component that conditionally renders a wrapped component. I am using enzyme and jest and the root component is rendered through the shallow() method.
The issue is testing if the Root component contains the wrapped component.

How would I test if the wrapped component exists without using the mount() render method?

*hoc.component.jsx*

```
export function HOC(Component) {
   render() {
     return <Component /> 
   }
}
```

*wrapped.component.jsx*

```
class WrappedComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export default HOC(WrappedComponent)
```

*root.component.jsx*

```
class RootComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
        condition ? ... :
         <WrappedComponent/>
     )
   }
}
```

When testing the *root.component.jsx* I would like to check if the WrappedComponent exists.

*root.component.spec.js*
    import { WrappedComponent } from 'WrappedComponent'

```
const wrapper = shallow(<RootComponent {...props}/>);
wrapper.find(WrappedComponent).length => returns 0
```

If I log wrapper.debug() I see the following:

```
...<HOC(WrappedComponent) />
```

How would I test the existence of the WrappedComponent while testing the RootComponent?

Comment: What's `condition`? Please, show how you import `WrappedComponent`. It's unclear whether it's equal to `HOC(WrappedComponent)` or `class WrappedComponent`. `wrapper.find(WrappedComponent) => returns 0` - `find` doesn't return a number. Are you checking its `length`? Please, show actual test code.

Comment: Condition could be anything, it either resolves to true or false. When false, it should render the WrappedComponent.

Comment: It's unknown whether it's true or false in your test. It could be a reason why you cannot assert the existence - because the comp doesn't exist. It's likely allows WrappedComponent to be rendered since you see it `wrapper.debug()` but the question shouldn't contain any ambiguities. So you import a WrappedComponent without HOC, don't you? You have to import a decorated component. I suppose it's default import in your case, `import WrappedComponent from 'WrappedComponent'`.

Comment: It is being rendered, I can confirm this in `wrapper.debug()`.


The wrapped component export statement is `export default HOC(WrappedComponent)`

In the spec file the wrappedComponent is imported as 
`import {WrappedComponent} from '..'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be possible to assert the existence of a component, as long as `WrappedComponent` in tests is not original component class but a component wrapped in HOC, i.e. `HOC(WrappedComponent)`.

If `HOC(WrappedComponent)` is default export, it should be:

```
import WrappedComponent from 'WrappedComponent'

...

const wrapper = shallow(<RootComponent {...props}/>);
expect(wrapper.find(WrappedComponent).length).toBe(1);
```

Comment: `<WrappedComponent/>` will be a child of `<HOC(WrappedComponent)/>`, since since it's shallow rendering, the child (second level) will not be rendered. Hence OP is seeing only `<HOC(WrappedComponent) />` when they do wrapper.debug()

Comment: @FrozenCrayon That's correct. There's ambiguity because HOC wrapper is called WrappedComponent too.

Comment: If you have `HOC(<WrappedComponent/>)` in your shallow render `wrapper.find(WrappedComponent)` will not work.

Comment: @FrozenCrayon As I just said, **`WrappedComponent` is `HOC(...)`**  in the example. `HOC(...)` doesn't have it's own specific name in the question, it's default export in wrapped.component.jsx .

Comment: Ah I see I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: I see the issue now, I'm exporting  the class as WrappedComponent as well. Instead I should have used the default export. Wow, thanks for the help @estus!

Comment: @BasG It would make more sense if their names weren't confusing, `import WrappedComponentWithHOC, { WrappedComponent } from 'WrappedComponent'`. In this case `WrappedComponentWithHOC` is direct child of `RootComponent` and can be accessed with `find`. While `WrappedComponent` is not a direct child of `RootComponent`, it's direct child of `WrappedComponentWithHOC`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the selector `'HOC(WrappedComponent)'`:

```
test('WrappedComponent is rendered', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<RootComponent {...props}/>);
    expect(wrapper.find('HOC(WrappedComponent)').length).toEqual(1);
}
```